CSS generic selector not working with SVG
If I have this HTML
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
  <g id="repeat">
    <path fill="currentColor"
      d="M20.3 13.43a1 1 0 0 0-1.25.65A7.14 7.14 0 0 1 12.18 19A7.1 7.1 0 0 1 5 12a7.1 7.1 0 0 1 7.18-7a7.26 7.26 0 0 1 4.65 1.67l-2.17-.36a1 1 0 0 0-1.15.83a1 1 0 0 0 .83 1.15l4.24.7h.17a1 1 0 0 0 .34-.06a.33.33 0 0 0 .1-.06a.78.78 0 0 0 .2-.11l.09-.11c0-.05.09-.09.13-.15s0-.1.05-.14a1.34 1.34 0 0 0 .07-.18l.75-4a1 1 0 0 0-2-.38l-.27 1.45A9.21 9.21 0 0 0 12.18 3A9.1 9.1 0 0 0 3 12a9.1 9.1 0 0 0 9.18 9A9.12 9.12 0 0 0 21 14.68a1 1 0 0 0-.7-1.25Z" />
  </g>
</svg>
<svg id="btnRepeat" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="button">
  <use href="#repeat"></use>
</svg>

and this CSS
:root {
  --norm-colour: green;
  --high-colour: red;
}

#btnRepeat {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15%;
  color: var(--norm-colour);
}

#btnRepeat:hover {
  color: var(--high-colour);
  cursor: pointer;
}

The svg colour is correct and changes on hover as expected.
If I change the selector from #btnRepeat:hover to a "generic" form of svg[id^="btn"]:hover the colour change on hover does not occur (though the cursor changes.) Why is it that the generic form fails?

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

I highly recommend to avoid IDs for CSS selectors as they introduce unnecessary high specificity. Overriding/modifying element styles is way easier by using classes. See codepen example

Because id selector has higher priority.


:root {
  --norm-colour: green;
  --high-colour: red;
}

[id^="btn"] {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15%;
  color: var(--norm-colour);
}

[id^="btn"]:hover {
  color: var(--high-colour);
  cursor: pointer;
}
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
        <g id="repeat">
            <path fill="currentColor" d="M20.3 13.43a1 1 0 0 0-1.25.65A7.14 7.14 0 0 1 12.18 19A7.1 7.1 0 0 1 5 12a7.1 7.1 0 0 1 7.18-7a7.26 7.26 0 0 1 4.65 1.67l-2.17-.36a1 1 0 0 0-1.15.83a1 1 0 0 0 .83 1.15l4.24.7h.17a1 1 0 0 0 .34-.06a.33.33 0 0 0 .1-.06a.78.78 0 0 0 .2-.11l.09-.11c0-.05.09-.09.13-.15s0-.1.05-.14a1.34 1.34 0 0 0 .07-.18l.75-4a1 1 0 0 0-2-.38l-.27 1.45A9.21 9.21 0 0 0 12.18 3A9.1 9.1 0 0 0 3 12a9.1 9.1 0 0 0 9.18 9A9.12 9.12 0 0 0 21 14.68a1 1 0 0 0-.7-1.25Z" />
        </g>
    </svg>
<svg id="btnRepeat" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="button">
        <use href="#repeat"></use>
    </svg>



According MDN doc How is specificity calculated?:



selector
weight (IDs-Classes, attributes and pseudo-classes-Elements and pseudo-elements)




#btnRepeat
1-0-0


[id^="btn"]:hover
0-2-0




I thought I knew about specificity but clearly not enough. Ok, an ID selector is more specific than a "generic" selector with a pseudo-class. Why does that supplant the :hover? [I tested what you did and it works but I don't understand why an ID has anything to do with hover?]

See this page: How is specificity calculated?.

I think I get it. Having an ID selector means that that selector also "owns" the pseudo classes that can be attached to it? So when I use a selector (with a pseudo class) of lower specificity it won't work because the ID selector I nominated earlier already owns it.

Specificity gives selection strength to all selectors. There is no concept of an earlier or later that can have more Specificity. An interesting case is #btnRepeat#btnRepeat#btnRepeat All it does is give the selector 2 more Specificity points  You would normally see these in the wild on Class selectors .foo.foo.foo
